# Why does this solid state relay have voltage on both terminals?

Tags: three-phase, solid-state-relay

I have an RA4850-D12 [1] SSR in an injection molding machine. The machine uses 240v, 3-phase power. The SSR is in the diagram for the circuit on page 7 for K81 [2]. You can see that terminal 1 of the SSR is connected to one of the 240v legs. I have disconnected points 94 and 95. This means that pin 2 on the SSR is only connected to a wire which isn't connected to anything else.

When I measure pin 1 to protective earth (PE), I get 120v RMS (expected). However, when I measure pin 2, I also get 120v RMS, with the same phase as the voltage on pin 1. The voltage between pins 1 and 2 is only 3-4v RMS. I removed the digital signal for pin 4 and shorted pins 3 and 4 together to ground them with the same result.

Why would I be getting voltage relative to PE for pin 2? It's not a phantom reading or insignificant power, either. For kicks, I let it touch PE and it tripped the circuit breaker, as expected.

1: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/1032/SSR_RA-2525416.pdf

2: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_mbgeQGryCEPEZo5bxtJjDMLyaaw9okz/view

Answer (score 1):

There is leakage current through the SSR because of the trigger circuit and the SCR or TRIAC that is used. Your voltmeter has a high resistance in its input and will be sensitive to small currents and show the voltage. Here is a link that will give you a better explanation then I can.

Comment: You say "here is a link" and don't give a link.

Comment: Thanks. Would love to see the link if you can post it again. Also, I'm having trouble reconciling this with two other oberservations: 1) when the heating elements (94-95) are connected, it shows 0v RMS across 94-95 (when pins 3-4 are 0v), and 2) Touching pin 2 to PE blew a 10A fuse. That's definitely not "low current". Can you help explain that? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

According to the block diagram in the data sheet, there is an RC snubber between output terminals.

Which you would kind of expect from a SSR intended for controlling inductive loads.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the RC elements in the block diagram would be the culprit. So, what's the point of the relay if it's always going to conduct? What is the difference between the state when pins 3-4 are 0v and when they are 3-32v (on)?

Comment: Also, what difference does this make in a resistive load? The heating elements are resistive heating bands. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Maxthecat The point of the SSR is listed in datasheet product description - it can be used with all kinds of loads, so you can use one single type SSR in your product to drive all kinds of loads without thinking which load requires which type of SSR. And the relay does not conduct. There just is an uncharged capacitor between SSR terminals. When SSR is off and load is disconnected, there is always 0V over the capacitor and no current flows through capacitor, so if one SSR terminal has 120VAC, then the other must have 120VAC too.